# Physically Identify a faulty USB drive on the Pi (3B+)

Tags: usb

I have four identical USB flash drives connected to a Raspberry Pi, one of which is (apparently) failing. I'm trying to find out which one..

It (the device is at /dev/sda) won't mount, with the following error:

```
mount: /dev/sda is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sda: can't read superblock
```

dmesg shows the following:

```
[3207772.134654] print_req_error: critical target error, dev sda, sector 0
[3207772.135995] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[3207772.136010] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x7 [current] 
[3207772.136021] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x27 ASCQ=0x0 
[3207772.136036] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x2a 2a 00 00 00 00 f0 00 00 10 00
[3207772.136046] print_req_error: critical target error, dev sda, sector 240
[3207772.140555] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is on
[3207772.140571] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 80 00
```

I can't create a new file system on it because of the write protection, and running something like

```
hdparm -r0 /dev/sda
```

to manually turn off the write protection makes no difference, the device still won't do anything - it won't mount and it won't do anything.

This leads me to believe, after a lot of googling around, that the flash drive is faulty. My next step is to take it out and try if it'll mount on another system. So now my next problem is: which of the four drives is it? The drives are all identical and there's no led on the flash drives indicating anything..

lsusb tells me this:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
```

Not very useful... How can I identify which of the four drives it is?

Note 1: besides the obvious idea unmounting all of them, putting them back one by one and seeing which ones mount when of course :)

Note 2: I know that putting 4 USB flash drives in a Pi is not a good idea performance-wise because of the hub design - the project is more of a 'can it work' thing instead of a 'will it perform well' :)

Thanks in advance for the help and advice!

Comment: I feel you are not using the correct tools for the job. With all 4 USB devices plugged in, run `lsblk --fs` at the cmdline & let us know what that result is. Also, you may wish to [read this for background](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ExternalDrives.md)

Comment: I don't think there are *any* right tools for the job here, if the issue is you need to identify which physical jack the drive is in.  Built-in USB buses (of which the pi only has one) may have consistent numbers (probably because they are built in and always register in the same order), but the individual USB jacks do not. I think this is an aspect of the protocol: The bus/hub identifies devices plugged into it to the operating system, but it does not differentiate one physical jack from another.  Put another way, there's no way to identify such a jack except by what is plugged into it.

Comment: @goldilocks: By "right tools" I meant that a) he is trying to mount a device instead of a partition, and b) `lsblk --fs` will give a clearer picture of what's actually plugged into his system. I feel you're correct, but there may be a work-around - depending on the OPs objectives: basically that is to use labels for each USB drive.

Comment: Adding a device or fs UUID or label would be a good idea if it fits within the whole context, then physically mark each drive so you can correspond them.

Comment: @goldilocks: I think so, too. I was going to suggest that the OP define labels that corresponded to the slot that it's plugged into; e.g. USB-ULH for Upper Left Hand USB slot, etc. Physical marking would help ensure they always go back into the same slot!

Comment: Thanks for both your comments and advice. 

@goldilocks: I feared that what you describe is indeed the nature of the USB protocol, but I wasn't sure. USB devices get a Device ID based on the order they are inserted / appear on the bus then, is that correct?

Comment: @Seamus: Thanks for the additional background info, I've added another comment to your answer below.

Comment: @pietervanwijngaarden Seems so.  If you look at the output from `lsusb`, pull a drive out, then put it right back in again, it will probably have a different `Device` number.  You could do that to figure out which is which, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command to obtain status on all block devices:

```
lsblk --fs
```

You should get something that looks like this:

> NAME        FSTYPE LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
>   sda
>   └─sda1      exfat  SANDISK16GB 5B00-9E5C                            /home/pi/mntThumbDrv
>   sdb
>   └─sdb1      vfat   PASSPORT2TB F2EC-14F5                            /home/pi/mntPassport
>   sdc
>   └─sdc1      vfat               809C-D7C7
>   mmcblk0
>   ├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   boot        5DB0-971B                            /boot
>   └─mmcblk0p2 ext4   rootfs      060b57a8-62bd-4d48-a471-0d28466d1fbb /

In this case:
* `sda` is a USB thumb drive with a single partition: `sda1`
* `sdb` is a USB WD "Passport" drive (i.e. spinning disk inside)
* `sdc` is a USB thumb drive with single partition, currently unmounted
* `mmcblk0` is the SD card with `boot` and `rootfs` partitions

If you want to mount a drive (partition), it needs a file system. Create the filesystem using the appropriate version of `mkfs` (e.g. `mkfs.fat` to create a FAT file system). Read `man mkfs.fat` for detailed usage & options.

You will not be able to depend on the system to make the same device assignment at each boot. For example, the USB device plugged into the ULH (upper left hand) USB slot may be designated `sda` today, but `sdc` a week from now when you reboot. Also, they will not have a long, unique UUID (read references below for explanations for this). This leaves you with only one option for making your USB drives "unique": the LABEL id.

As discussed in the comments to your question, you could implement the following system to keep track of your USB devices:

1. Physically mark each device (tape, marker, etc), and
2. Designate a unique LABEL for each device when you create the filesystem using `mkfs.XXX`

Let us know how you get on after you've tried this. We'll try to help with any detailed follow-up questions you may have.

FURTHER READING:
* [Differences between /dev/sda and /dev/sda1](https://serverfault.com/questions/338937/differences-between-dev-sda-and-dev-sda1)
* [What does /dev/sda for linux mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/558156/what-does-dev-sda-for-linux-mean)
* [How To Partition and Format Storage Devices in Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-partition-and-format-storage-devices-in-linux)
* [How To Connect an External Drive to Raspberry Pi?](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ExternalDrives.md)

Comment: This is not clear from my question, but I'm aware that I shouldn't mount devices directly. In my fstab I'm using the UUID's from `blkid`. Those UUID's are persistent across reboots and independent of the order in which the drives are either connected to the USB bus, or mounted on the system, correct? The step I should have done to identify failed drives is the physical labelling :). It didn't occur to me that I wouldn't be able to identify them.

Comment: UUIDs (for USB devices) aren't a good option for maintaining a unique handle for a particular drive. Using LABELs created using `mkfs.XXXX` is stable, and the LABEL can be used in your `fstab`. See the last reference above.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer, as far as I can see now, is that you **cannot** identify which *physical* USB port/jack a drive is connected to from the information in the Operating System alone.

The `lsusb`, `blkid` and `lsblk` tools will tell you which (block storage) devices are on the USB bus (and if they are mounted, which file system and mount point they have), but if you add multiple *identical* devices to the USB bus, your best bet is to connect and mount them one by one and label/mark them (physically, not in the OS) to differentiate them from each other.

And use the mount procedures that @Seamus provided, see answer above.